# Triangle pattern in Java with while loop

Tags: java, design-patterns, while-loop

Hello I was Tasked to make an triangle generator with the  symbols and number of rows that users want in java with while loop it worked like this.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
```

But I want like this

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
  ******
 *******
********
```

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

class Main {
 public static void main(String args[]){
  
  ////////////OBJECTS///////////////////////

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
  ///////////////////////INPUTS//////////

  System.out.println("Please Enter how many rows do you want");
  int inp = sc.nextInt();
  
  System.out.println("Which symbol do you want");
  String str2 = sc2.nextLine();
 ////////////////VARIABLES///////////////////

  int c = 0; 
  String str = "";
  String str3 = "";
  System.out.println("=====================");

  ///////LOGIC/////////////////////////////

  while(c != inp){
   str = str+str2; 
   System.out.println(str);
   c=c+1;
  }

////////////////////////////////////////////
  
 }
 
}
```

Do you know that how can i solve it with this logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one `Scanner`, and the algorithm is much easier if you use [`String.repeat(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)). First repeat space `inp - c` times, then repeat your "symbol" `c` times. Like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Enter how many rows do you want");
int inp = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Which symbol do you want");
String symbol = sc.nextLine(); // You had a good name in the prompt.
int c = 1;
System.out.println("=====================");
while (c <= inp) {
    System.out.print(" ".repeat(inp - c));
    System.out.println(symbol.repeat(c));
    c++;
}
```

Example output

```
Please Enter how many rows do you want
5
Which symbol do you want
*
=====================
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Answer (score 2):

For each row of the pattern, you can form a pattern between the whitespaces and the character that you are trying to print.

In case the input is 5, you can see that the whitespaces are decreasing (,  first row 4, second row 3 )  and the character is increasing( first row 1 , second row 2 ) and the sum of number of whitespaces and the character(*) is constant( equal to 5)
Therefore, for each row, you have to print whitespaces and character for a number of times.

Also, you don't need 2 scanner objects to read the inputs. After reading the integer, you can use scan.next() to read the last character([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo))

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //////////// OBJECTS///////////////////////

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        /////////////////////// INPUTS//////////

        System.out.println("Please Enter how many rows do you want");
        int inp = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        // sc.next();
        System.out.println("Which symbol do you want");
        String str2 = sc.nextLine();
        //////////////// VARIABLES///////////////////

        int c = 1;
        String str = "";
        String str3 = "";
        System.out.println("=====================");

        /////// LOGIC/////////////////////////////

         int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    while (i <= inp) {
        while (j < inp - i) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
        }
        while (j < inp) {
            System.out.print(str2);
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }

        sc.close();
        ////////////////////////////////////////////

    }

}
```

and the output is

```
Please Enter how many rows do you want
5
Which symbol do you want
*
=====================
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Comment: Thanks but I want help with while loop

Comment: @Nobody have edited it and used while loop

Answer (score 2):

I cant edit the answer of @Elliott Frisch. Thats why I am giving this answer. ***You have to add only 3 lines extra to do what you want and there is no need to remove your Scanner object***

First import java.io.*

```
import java.io.*;
```

In variables you have to add this line.

```
String str3 = " ";
```

And in while loop of logic section you have to replace this code .

```
System.out.println(str);
```

To this;

```
System.out.println(str3.repeat(inp)+str2);
```

And this is your whole code after editing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
 public static void main(String args[]){
  
  ////////////OBJECTS///////////////////////

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
  ///////////////////////INPUTS//////////
  System.out.println("Please Enter how many rows do you want");
  int inp = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Which symbol do you want");
  String str2 = sc2.nextLine();
 ////////////////VARIABLES///////////////////
 
  String str = str2;
  String str3 = " ";
  System.out.println("=====================");

  ///////LOGIC/////////////////////////////
while(inp != 0){
 
 System.out.println(str3.repeat(inp)+str2);
 str2 = str+str2; 
 inp=inp-1; 
}

/////////////////END///////////////////////////
 }
 
}
```

And this is the output

```
Please Enter how many rows do you want
10
Which symbol do you want
#
=====================
          #
         ##
        ###
       ####
      #####
     ######
    #######
   ########
  #########
 ##########
```

THANKS I HOPE IT WILL HELP YOU